# How to access Camunda Cloud from inside corporate network

Tags: java, camunda, zeebe

I’m building a PoC with Zeebe

I was able to run from my local pc the Java client at https://github.com/camunda-cloud/camunda-cloud-get-started

Now, when I try to run it from my corporate PC, I’m getting the error below. I understand that I need to fix some network configuration to make it work. Is this configuration documented anywhere?

Many thanks.

---

```
18:42:51.788 [grpc-default-executor-0] WARN  io.camunda.zeebe.client.job.poller - Failed to activated jobs for worker default and job type email
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 19.913053500s. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=19915792700, waiting_for_connection]]]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535) ~[grpc-api-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:478) [grpc-stub-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:557) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:69) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:738) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:717) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
18:42:53.374 [grpc-default-executor-2] WARN  io.camunda.zeebe.client.job.poller - Failed to activated jobs for worker default and job type email
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535) ~[grpc-api-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:478) [grpc-stub-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:557) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:69) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:738) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:717) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) [grpc-core-1.40.1.jar:1.40.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: d05e6b8a-51ef-45b1-a532-0fe11c01f0e4.bru-2.zeebe.camunda.io/34.76.215.247:443
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707) ~[netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.68.Final.jar:4.1.68.Final]
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I think you need to make sure that the host (camunda.io) is in the allowed list, the protocol is allowed grpc / http2, the port but no there is no document about that.

Comment: Tks @Zelldon camunda.io is allowed. I can connect to the console. What I cannot do is access Zeebe from the Java application.